# extracting date field from the lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file like this

```
Sampleoutput1[Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/Error(10
Sampleoutput1Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/[Fri Jun 11 06:11:59 2016]Error(10
```

I need to extract date field  and add this date as column with delimited ($).Date can be present anywhere in the file.

```
[Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]$Sampleoutput1[Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/Error(10
[Fri Jun 11 06:11:59 2016]$Sampleoutput1Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/[Fri Jun 11 06:11:59 2016]Error(10
```

Comment: Sorry . I am not able to use format code. Please dont mind

Comment: Why `grep -o '\[\(\w\{3\} \)\{2\}[0-9: ]\{14,16\}\]'` didn't satisfy you?

Comment: Thanks Costas. Its working. is it possible to add this date with delimiter($) to the input file like                                                                                    [Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]$Sampleoutput1[Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/Error(10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the date is always enclosed in `[` ... `]` and that's the first `[` on the line we can use a number of methods.  Two common ones I use:

Using two `cut` commands (the lazy option, but it's very easy to understand what it does):

```
cut -d'[' -f2 $srcfile | cut -d ']' -f1
```

The standard `sed` option, using a simple regex:

```
sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)].*/\1/' $srcfile
```

If your output is more complicated with multiple `[` characters in it then you'll need to use the `sed` option with a more complicated string:

```
sed 's/.*\[\(... ... .. ..:..:.. ....\)].*/\1/' $srcfile
```

EDIT: The revised question wants this added to the front of the string, leaving the rest of the line untouched.  So we use the `sed` variant with a minor change:

```
sed 's/\(.*\[\(... ... .. ..:..:.. ....\)].*\)/[\2]$\1/' $srcfile
```

Result:

```
[Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]$Sampleoutput1[Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/Error(10
[Fri Jun 11 06:11:59 2016]$Sampleoutput1Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/[Fri Jun 11 06:11:59 2016]Error(10
```

Comment: thanks Harris. is it possible to add this date with delimiter($) to the input file like [Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]$Sampleoutput1[Fri Jun 10 06:11:59 2016]Local/ESSBASE0///139929633446208/Error(10 –

Comment: See edit'd answer