# shell - extracting date & time from logs

Tags: text-processing, logs

I have web server log files that look like this:

```
2001:67c:1220:80c:d4:985a:df2c:d717 - - [22/Feb/2019:07:49:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 58266 "-" "curl/7.61.1"
2001:67c:1220:80c:d4:985a:df2c:d717 - - [22/Feb/2019:08:49:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 58341 "-" "curl/7.61.1"
2001:67c:1220:808::93e5:8ad - - [22/Feb/2019:08:56:10 +0100] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1550822170.2184400558471679687500 HTTP/1.1" 200 3279 "https://ios-example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1550822170.2184400558471679687500" "WordPress/4.9.9; https://ios-example.com"
...
```

I need to extract dates and times in this format `22/Feb/2019:07:49:01`.

This is what I have now (shamelessly copied from this thread: [extracting date field from the lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299726/extracting-date-field-from-the-lines?newreg=7cd55f621cb34c48aff2d31b26098faa)):

```
file="filename"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "`cut -d '[' -f2 $line | cut -d ' ' -f1`" # echoing now for testing purposes
done <"$file"
```

And this is the output when I run the script:

```
cut: '2001:67c:1220:80c:d4:985a:df2c:d717': Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: '[22/Feb/2019:07:49:01': Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: +0100]: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: '"GET': Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: /: je adresářem
cut: 'HTTP/1.1"': Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: 200: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: 58266: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: '"-"': Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
cut: '"curl/7.61.1"': Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
22/Feb/2019:08:49:01
22/Feb/2019:08:56:10
22/Feb/2019:08:56:10
22/Feb/2019:09:24:33
22/Feb/2019:09:24:33
22/Feb/2019:09:43:13
22/Feb/2019:09:43:24
...
```

"Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje" means "Directory or file does not exist".

For a reason unknown to me, it does not work on the first line of the log file, but works fine with the rest of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made multiple mistakes  :

- cut use a file name as argument
- you forget some double quote ( **"** )

So if i rewrite you example , with a minimal number of change :

- the use of **$(** instead of **`** . this is more robust and it can be recursive .
- the use of **${VARIABLE_NAME}** instead of $VARIABLE_NAME . this is more robust

a new version of

```
file="filename"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    EXTRACT_DATE=$( echo "$line" | cut -d '[' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1  )
    echo "${EXTRACT_DATE}"        
done <"$file"
```

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you very much for a quick answer!

Comment: There is absolutely _no_ difference between `$var` and `${var}`.  Both mean exactly the same thing.  The important thing is the double quoting of the variable expansion. Your code uses both variations of `$var` and `${var}` for no good reason. The only place where you _need_ `${var}` is when the expansion is part of a string and the very next character is a character that is valid in a variable name, as in `"${var}x"`.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue, which creates the errors, is that you using the read line in `$line` as a filename for `cut` to read.

You are also using `echo` to output the result of a command substitution. This is an anti-pattern.  Just run the pipeline, without `echo` nor command substitution. It will output its result to the terminal by itself.

Here, we use `printf` to give `cut` the line read from the file:

```
file="filename"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" | cut -d '[' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1
done <"$file"
```

The next thing to note is that the `while` loop is totally unnecessary.  You are calling `cut` twice for *each line* in the log file.  The `cut` utility is perfectly capable of reading the file line by line by itself:

```
file="filename"

cut -d '[' -f2 "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

Or, you could use GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\[)[^ ]+' "$file"
```

(This extracts everything up to the first space after the first `[`)

or standard `sed`,

```
sed 's/\].*//; s/.*\[//; s/ .*//' "$file"
```

(This deletes everything after the first `]`, then deletes everything to the first `[`, then chops of the space and the rest ofter that)

Related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)